# Передать/получить данные из custom ячейки таблицы

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uiviewcontroller

Есть кастомная ячейка в таблице. В этой ячейки есть button. Мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку перейти на другой ViewController и передать туда данные из ячейки. Из этого нового ViewController я должен вернуть обработанные данные обратно в ячейку таблице. Под данными я подразумеваю переменную типа UIColor. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как вы передаете UIColor и вам нужен результат изменения, лучше воспользоваться UserDefaults и оттуда получать/сохранять UIColor

```
extension UserDefaults {

    func color(forKey key: String) -> UIColor? {
        var color: UIColor?
        if let colorData = data(forKey: key) {
            color = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData) as? UIColor
        }
        return color
    }

    func set(_ value: UIColor?, forKey key: String) {
        var colorData: Data?
        if let color = value {
            colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color)
        }
        set(colorData, forKey: key)
    }

}
```

Использование:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(UIColor.white, forKey: "white")
let whiteColor = UserDefaults.standard.color(forKey: "white")
```

Comment: То есть в контроллере в который я перехожу мне нужен свой инициализатор?

Comment: я поправил ответ, лучше через userDefaults это делать на текущем контроллере считываешь и отображаешь, а в новый переходишь там хочешь - устанавливай новый цвет или же просто отображай

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас код переварю:) Завтра напишу помогло ли это.

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос - что лучше использовать: userDefaults or Singleton?

Comment: Зависит от того как вы хотите хранить значение, синглтон держит в оперативной памяти ( так как обычный static ), userDefaults хранит данные в постоянной памяти, то есть после перезапуска приложения ваши данные останутся.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал вам использовать паттерн делегат, в данном случае делегатом будет ViewController (VC), который занимается отображением ячейки.

- Для этого объявите протокол SetColorDelegate с методом
  setColor(color:UIColor),
- В этом методе вы можете сохранять цвет в переменную, и по didSet к примеру перезагружать таблицу так что бы ячейка обновилась и
  показывала новый цвет.
- При нажатии на кнопку в ячейке, получите доступ к VC который будет показан (если пользуетесь Segue то это будет свойство
  destinationViewController) и выставляйте  у него делегат.
- При смене цвета во втором VC дергайте метод делегата delegate.setColor. И автоматом у вас будут выполнены действия из п2

Comment: Спасибо, на днях попробую.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Сделал всё через call back.